# Factory Class not found while testing ZF2 app

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm new on ZF2 and I have a problem to test a Factory Class.

This is my contollers.config.php

```
   <?php

return array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Application\Controller\Index' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController',
        'Application\Controller\SystemStatus' => 'Application\Controller\SystemStatusController',
    ),
    'factories' => array(
        'Application\Controller\HomePage' => 'Application\Controller\Factory\HomePageControllerFactory',
    ),
);
```

My path to the Factory Class is:

/app/src/module/Application/src/Application/Controller/Factory/HomePageControllerFactory.php

And the file looks like:

```
<?php
namespace Application\Controller\Factory;

use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use Application\Controller\HomePageController;

class HomePageControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface {

    /**
     * @param ServiceLocatorInterface $sm
     * @return HomePageController|mixed
     */
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $sm)
    {
        $queryParams = $sm->getServiceLocator()->get('path\path');
        $service = $sm->getServiceLocator()->get('path\path');
        return new HomePageController($queryParams, $service);
    }

}
```

My path to the Test is:
/app/tests/ApplicationTest/Integration/Controller/Factory/HomePageControllerFactoryTest.php

and the only that I have inside is:

```
<?php

namespace ApplicationTest\Integration\Controller\Factory;

use Application\Controller\Factory\HomePageControllerFactory;
use PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase as TestCase;

class HomePageControllerFactoryTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * @var HomePageControllerFactory
     */
    private $underTest;

    public function setUp()
    {
       $this->underTest = new HomePageControllerFactory();
    }

public function testCreateService()
    {

      /*Nothing*/

    }

}
```

and when I run the test this is the ouput

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Application\Controller\Factory\HomePageControllerFactory' not found in /apps/tests/ApplicationTest/Integration/Controller/Factory/HomePageControllerFactoryTest.php on line 17
```

Bootstrap.php is located /app/tests/Bootstrap.php

content:

```
    <?php

namespace ApplicationTest;

use Zend\Loader\AutoloaderFactory
    , Zend\Mvc\Service\ServiceManagerConfig
    , Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager;

date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
chdir(dirname(__DIR__));

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

class Bootstrap
{
    private static $instance;
    private $serviceManager;

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (!isset(static::$instance)) {
            $class = get_class();
            static::$instance = new $class;
        }

        return static::$instance;
    }

    public static function init()
    {
        AutoloaderFactory::factory();
        static::getInstance();
    }

    public function getServiceManager()
    {
        if (!isset($this->serviceManager)) {
            $this->serviceManager = new ServiceManager(new ServiceManagerConfig());
        }
        return $this->serviceManager;
    }

    public function setServiceManager(ServiceManager $sm)
    {
        $this->serviceManager = $sm;
    }

    public function getConfig()
    {
        if (is_readable(__DIR__ . '/TestConfig.php')) {
            return require __DIR__ . '/TestConfig.php';
        } else {
            return require './src/config/application.config.php';
        }
    }

    private function __construct()
    {
    }
}

Bootstrap::init();
```

I'm stuck on this, I don't know why I can not instance an object of HomePageControllerFactory

Comment: Does your phpunit.xml.dist specify a bootstrap file which has an autoloader in it so that the class is loaded by PHP?

Comment: Yes, I just updated the topic with my Bootstrap file

Comment: Cool, using composer? You might need to add something like `"Application": "src/module/Application/src/"` to the `"psr-0"` section of your composer.json specifying the autoloads and then run `php composer.phar dump-autoload`

Comment: I have tried  adding "Application\\": "src/" or "Application\\": "src/module" but no lucky :(

Comment: I just edited my comment - try "src/module/Application/src"?

Comment: You are my hero, add what you said as a answer please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using composer then you will need to include the path to the Application classes in the autoload section of composer.json:

```
...
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "Application": "src/module/Application/src/"
    }
}
...
```

And then rerun composer to generate the autoload files again:

```
$ php composer.phar dump-autoload
```